# Does 3.5 have a feat like Mounted Combat but for saving throws?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, feats, mounted-combat

Mounted Combat allows you to replace your mount’s AC with your Ride check once per round. But enemies rarely target my mount with attacks—my mount is far more likely to be caught in the area of an effect that requires a saving throw than she is to be attacked. Is there any feat that works like Mounted Combat, but for saving throws?

I know Pathfinder has one, [Indomitable Mount](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/indomitable-mount-combat-local/), but since Pathfinder unconscionably nerfed Mounted Combat to use an immediate action, and Indomitable Mount inherits that (making the two feats mutually exclusive, despite one requiring the other), I am interested to see if a similar concept was ever published for 3.5e, which presumably would have retained Mounted Combat’s 1/round usage rather than immediate-action usage.

Official or licensed 3.5e material only, please. Otherwise, go nuts.

Answer (score 6):

The Saddleback feat from Player's Guide to Faerun allows this for reflex saves (including your own reflex saves, not just your mount's). It also allows you to take 10 on ride checks even if rushed or threatened.

It does come with the restriction of being a regional feat, requiring you to take it at 1st level, be your only regional feat, and requiring you to be a human from Cormyr, Dambrath, the Hordelands, Narfell, Nimbral, the North, or the Western Heartlands.

Comment: Good to know! Reflex saves are the ones I’m least worried about, but getting it for both myself and my mount, and getting to take 10, adds a fair amount of value. Worthy of consideration, certainly.

Comment: If it's more palatable, there's an alternative version of the feat Saddleback (*Dragon* #315 65) that's, instead, a Kara-tur *ancestor* feat (hence allowing a creature to take a different Forgotten Realms regional feat, ancestor feats still being limited to only one but not dictated by region). However, that feat doesn't allow the take 10 on Ride skill checks.